# ¿Pudo venir "garete" del francés "être égaré"?

Tags: etimología, verbos

En el DLE se recoge la palabra *garete* como parte las expresiones *al garete* e *irse al garete*:

> **[garete](https://dle.rae.es/garete)**
>
> ```
> De or. inc.
> ```
>
> **al garete**
>
> 1. loc. adv. **a la deriva**.
> 2. expr. coloq. U. para manifestar desagrado, enfado o rechazo. *Lo mandó al garete.*
>
> **irse** algo **al garete**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Fracasar o malograrse. *Su fortuna se fue al garete.*

Tratando de indagar un poco en ese "origen incierto", encontré en el Corominas que el origen que considera más probable es el que afirma que procede del francés *être égaré*, que vendría a significar "estar perdido". El verbo *[égarer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/%C3%A9gar%C3%A9)* es muy antiguo en francés, documentándose desde el siglo XI. Su significado ya en el siglo XII tenía el sentido de "no ir por el buen camino", lo que encajaría con el sentido de "a la deriva" que tiene *al garete*, a lo cual hay que sumar la semejanza fonética.

Sin embargo, Corominas no quiso dar la etimología por cierta debido a que no encontró referencias en francés del uso de *égarer* en contextos náuticos. Así que [pregunté en el sitio de francés](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/43324/20830), y básicamente me respondieron que sí, que ya en el siglo XVI se usaba *égarer* (entonces *esgarer*) en contextos náuticos:

[image: Case de égarer]

> Entre lesdits deux coins on se dirige vers le Hontswijck qui est une fort mauvaise entrée et un dangereux passage, d'autant qu'en ce lieu plusieurs navires **s'égarent**, pour avoir à cet endroit trop peu tourné.

El autor de la respuesta afirma que el texto, aunque diga que el pasaje por el que cruzaban los barcos era peligroso, no hace referencia a que los barcos se hundieran, sino que más bien se perdían.

Así que definitivamente el verbo sí se usaba para indicar barcos a la deriva o perdidos. Y para rematar, la edición de 1899 del DLE afirma que sí, que *garete* viene de *égaré*, aunque esa etimología fue descartada en revisiones posteriores.

La expresión *al garete* se documenta en español desde el siglo XVI:

> *Miércoles 19 de Henero de 1594.*
>
> *Víspera de San Sebastian me trujeron dos cargas de agua del rio clara como los ojos, porque de claro que estaba el rio parecia que estaba verde, y jueves 20 de Henero, dia de San Sebastian, amaneció el rio salido, y estaba el agua pasada la cruz del Altozano, enfrente de mi puerta, y ví venir muchos barcos **al garete** y se ahogó mucha gente, y una nao que estaba junto á la puente: se desamarró y fué á dar á San Juan de Alfarache [...].*

Resumiendo: la palabra *garete* se documenta en español en contextos náuticos desde el siglo XVI al menos, igual que en francés el verbo *égarer* en los mismos contextos, ambas se usaban de forma similar y son fonéticamente parecidas. Tenemos todas las papeletas para dar con la etimología real de la palabra, pero ¿cómo se pasa de *égarer* (o *esgarer*) a *garete*? ¿Cómo se le añadió esa sílaba *-te* final? Corominas dice que pudo estar influenciada por otras palabras como *garito* o *garita*, esta última recogida en diccionarios desde el siglo XVI también y en textos desde el siglo XIV. ¿Pudo ser eso, o quizá alguna conjugación del verbo *égarer* en la que se pronunciara una *t* final, como el *ésgarent* del texto, seguida de vocal?

Comment: I assumed it was related to the English word _garret_,  "a living space at the top of a house or larger residential building, often small, dismal, and cramped," (Wikipedia) which you might send someone to as a sign of disapproval as in the second definition you quote for _al garete_

Comment: @mdewey most interesting. Is the word "garret" old enough as to appear in texts from the 16th century or before?

Comment: Probably not as although it entered our language in Middle English via Old French it meant something different then and the typical garret you see in Paris buildings (in French _chambre de bonne_) is 18th century.

Answer (score 2):

Sobre la adquisición de la *-te* final, el propio Corominas indica en el artículo sobre "garete":

> "Más  probable  es  que *étre  égaré*  'ir  sin dirección,  andar  a  la  ventura' fuese  adaptado  por  los  marinos  del  Cantábrico en la  forma  *estar *a  garete*  (y  después  *al  garete*),  **porque  las  palabras  pronunciadas  con  *-é*  en  francés  (escrito  *-et*)  suelen  corresponder  a  voces  españolas  en  *-ete*"** ...